# Jmeter certificate not working in most sites

Tags: firefox, jmeter, certificate

After I installed the Jmeter Certificate I still see error for missing certificate. I can access few sites which I couldn't before installing the certificate, but still in most sites I get the error. I use FireFox and Jmeter 5.4.1. How to fix this errors after I already have installed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Your "not working" statement doesn't tell the full story, I can think of one possible reason:

- You visited a web site over [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol before installing JMeter's certificate
- You're trying to open the same web site after installing JMeter certificate
- Firefox [detects certificates mismatch](https://aboutssl.org/how-to-tackle-ssl-certificate-mismatch-error/) and prevents the website from opening

The easiest solution is to completely [delete your browsing history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox) or if you don't want to do this [create a new "clean" Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles) which will be used just for recording purposes.

More information: [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

Also be aware of [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: I have already deleted the history, the old certificate, cookies and any data, even deleted Jmeter and extracted it again and then added the new certificate, same result. I also renamed the FireFox certificates file to get it to generate a new one before start